# PHP cURL refuses to POST to website

Tags: php, post, curl

I would like to ask for some kind assistance. I've been trying for hours reading different articles and Q&As for a possible cure as to why PHP cURL refuses to POST. But none of the methods I try are giving any results.

The website I am attempting to POST to is "pixiv.net". Here is my current PHP code:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/pixiv-cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/pixiv-cookie.txt');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.pixiv.net/');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.pixiv.net');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    echo curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)){
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        echo 'Operation completed without any errors<br>'; }

    //--------------------------------------------

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.secure.pixiv.net/login.php/');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    $httpHeader = array(
        'Host: www.pixiv.net',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36',
        'DNT: 1',
        'Referer: http://www.pixiv.net',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch',
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.4,zh;q=0.2,fr-FR;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2'
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeader);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $postData='
        mode=login
        &return_to=%2F
        &pixiv_id=#####
        &pass=#####
        &skip=1
    ';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

    echo curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    unset($ch);
?>
```

On the website, the HTML portion of the login area is as follows:

```
<form action="https://www.secure.pixiv.net/login.php" method="post" data-time="1429509525" data-text-confirm="...">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="login">
<input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="/">
<div class="id"><input type="text" class="js-placeholder" id="login_pixiv_id" name="pixiv_id" value="" maxlength="255" placeholder="pixiv ID or Email"></div>
<div class="pass-signin"><input type="password" class="js-placeholder" id="login_password" name="pass" value="" maxlength="32" placeholder="Password"><input type="submit" id="login_submit" value="Login" class="ui-button"></div>
<div class="save-forgotpass"><label><input name="skip" type="checkbox" checked="" value="1">Remember me</label>
<div><a href="https://www.secure.pixiv.net/reminder.php" class="reminder">Forgot ID or password?</a>
<a href="https://www.secure.pixiv.net/login.php?return_to=%2F" class="ssl-login">Secure sign-in through SSL (https)</a></div>
</div></form>
```

So far, the GET works fine in saving the cookie from the website. I set the HTTP Headers to be the exact same as my current browser's, as well as some other things to help spoof the connection. I blanked out my login details here, but I assure you that they're correct.

The header returned by the website is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 20 Apr 2015 18:59:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Host-Time: 113
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 20 Apr 2015 19:03:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 564
Connection: keep-alive
```

Does anybody have an idea as to what I could be doing wrong? If it helps, the website does load (GET) some of their own images, which show as 403's in my browser's console (probably because the website detected that it's not a same-domain request). This PHP page is being run locally on XAMPP, and I'm not getting any errors from cURL.

Comment: Shouldn't you be posting to `"https://www.secure.pixiv.net/login.php"`?

Comment: What I meant was you should be posting to the page which is the action of the form.

Comment: Yep, I tried that, as you mentioned. It gave me "Curl error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate".

Comment: What a surprise. You can either define the CURLOPT_CAPATH or CURLOPT_CAINFO.

Comment: Or you can just `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`

Comment: Okay, I tried that line. Something happened now, but pixiv is giving me an alert saying that "This page is not pixiv.net!".

Comment: Set CURLOPT_HEADER to true and show the results.

Comment: See the answer below. And you should have a space after the colon in your headers.

Comment: I have edited my question with the edits I made, as well as the new header, for you to check out. I will try maalls' suggestion now. EDIT: Okay, I tried maalls' edit as well. Now the site is returning two things; a slightly changed header (my question is updated), and a bunch of stuff that couldn't be decoded by my browser (even after choosing various language encodings). The page is a 403, though.

Comment: A 403 is forbidden. Try removing `CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER` and set `CURLOPT_REFERER` to be `http://pixiv.net`

Comment: @frz3993 Okay, I tried rearranging some of the code and double-checking my HTTP headers. I have edited my question to reflect these changes. I get two header responses now, which I have shown as well, that isolates the issue to being solely the POST request giving a 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Where will it redirect on successful login?

Comment: Update: I checked Chrome's Network tab when logging in ordinarily, and it shows that it first POST to "/login.php", then GET "www.pixiv.net", and then finally GET "/mypage.php" before loading up everything. Is this helpful to know? I thought something was odd when the site kept telling me, "This page isn't pixiv.net!" Is it possibly because the server feels that my PHP script isn't redirecting properly, and feels it is a fake request? @frz3993

Comment: If you can get me a username and password I will show you how to get on.  I could not get past the capcha to create a log on.

Comment: I found someone used username and password as their login, so was able to log on with curl successfully.  see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update 2

### First request

**Request header** (http://www.pixiv.net/)

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Host: www.pixiv.net
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
```

**Response header** (http://www.pixiv.net/)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 01:12:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Host-Time: 113
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=c40dbb30394766ec885c61f7e08e00fb; expires=Tue, 21-Apr-2015 02:12:07 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=.pixiv.net
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: p_ab_id=2; expires=Tue, 21-Apr-2020 01:12:07 GMT; Max-Age=157852800; path=/; domain=.pixiv.net
Set-Cookie: p_ab_id=2; expires=Tue, 21-Apr-2020 01:12:07 GMT; Max-Age=157852800; path=/; domain=.pixiv.net
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

### Second request

**Request header** (https://www.secure.pixiv.net/login.php)

This has a cookie from previous response.

```
POST /login.php HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Host: www.secure.pixiv.net
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: PHPSESSID=c40dbb30394766ec885c61f7e08e00fb; p_ab_id=2
Content-Length: 56
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

**Response header** (https://www.secure.pixiv.net/login.php)

This redirects to http://www.pixiv.net/  (See `Location` in headers),
then http://www.pixiv.net/ redirects to http://www.pixiv.net/mypage.php.

It did not alter the cookies so I skipped http://www.pixiv.net/ and
when right to http://www.pixiv.net/mypage.php

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 01:12:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Host-Time: 62
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
P3P: CP="THIS IS NOT P3P"
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=509719_83607aedd2945280c7879fab036c5fb0; expires=Tue, 21-Apr-2015 02:12:08 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=.pixiv.net
Set-Cookie: device_token=d14a832ce615d42daae571775215d712; expires=Thu, 21-May-2015 01:12:08 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/; domain=.pixiv.net
Location: http://www.pixiv.net/
```

NOTICE: Last line of Response Header `Location: http://www.pixiv.net/`
This is the URL the Browser is being redirected to.

but I skipped `Location: http://www.pixiv.net/` because it did not set new cookies.

`http://www.pixiv.net/` just created another 302 redirect to `http://www.pixiv.net/mypage.php`

### Third request

**Request header** (http://www.pixiv.net/mypage.php)

```
GET /mypage.php HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Host: www.pixiv.net
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: PHPSESSID=509719_83607aedd2945280c7879fab036c5fb0; p_ab_id=2; device_token=d14a832ce615d42daae571775215d712
```

**Response header** (http://www.pixiv.net/mypage.php)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 01:12:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Host-Time: 62
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: module_orders_mypage=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22everyone_new_illusts%22%2C%22visible%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22spotlight%22%2C%22visible%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22featured_tags%22%2C%22visible%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22contests%22%2C%22visible%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22following_new_illusts%22%2C%22visible%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22mypixiv_new_illusts%22%2C%22visible%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22booth_follow_items%22%2C%22visible%22%3Atrue%7D%5D; expires=Wed, 20-Apr-2016 01:12:08 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; domain=.pixiv.net
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

---

### FINAL PHP CODE

Get new cookies from a 302 redirect.  Makes third request with the 302 URL.

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.pixiv.net";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
$url = 'http://www.pixiv.net/';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$info = var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true);
$fp = fopen('pixiv.html','w');
fwrite($fp,"$data\n\n$info");
fclose($fp);
if (curl_errno($ch)){
    $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $head = substr($data,0,$skip);
  $e = 0;
  while(true){
    $s = strpos($head,'Set-Cookie: ',$e);
    if (!$s){break;}
    $s += 12;
    $e = strpos($head,';',$s);
    $cookie = substr($head,$s,$e-$s) ;
    $s = strpos($cookie,'=');
    $key = substr($cookie,0,$s);
    $value = substr($cookie,$s);
    $cookies[$key] = $value;

  }
 $cookie = '';
 $delim = '';
 foreach ($cookies as $k => $v){
   $cookie .= "$delim$k$v";
   $delim = '; ';
 }
}

$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.secure.pixiv.net";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
$request[] = "Cookie: $cookie";
$postData = 'mode=login&return_to=%2F&pixiv_id=username&pass=password';
$url = 'https://www.secure.pixiv.net/login.php';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)){
    $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $info = var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true);
  $fp = fopen('pixivLogin.html','w');
  fwrite($fp, "\n------------------$data\n\n$info");
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $head = substr($data,0,$skip);
  $e = 0;
  while(true){
    $s = strpos($head,'Set-Cookie: ',$e);
    if (!$s){break;}
    $s += 12;
    $e = strpos($head,';',$s);
    $cookie = substr($head,$s,$e-$s) ;
    $s = strpos($cookie,'=');
    $key = substr($cookie,0,$s);
    $value = substr($cookie,$s);
    $cookies[$key] = $value;

  }
 $cookie = '';
 $delim = '';
 foreach ($cookies as $k => $v){
   $cookie .= "$delim$k$v";
   $delim = '; ';
 }
}


$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.pixiv.net";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
$request[] = "Cookie: $cookie";
$url = 'http://www.pixiv.net/mypage.php';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$info = var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true);
$fp = fopen('pixiv2.html','w');
fwrite($fp,"$data\n\n$info");
fclose($fp);
if (curl_errno($ch)){
    $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $head = substr($data,0,$skip);
  $data = substr($data,$skip);
  echo $data;
```

end of update2

---

### UPDATE

This starts fresh every login by getting a new cookie to use for login each time it is executed.

This goes to http://www.pixiv.net/ and gets the cookie for the login. 
 
Worked well for me.

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.pixiv.net";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
$url = 'http://www.pixiv.net/';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)){
    $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
```

Gets the response header:

```
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $head = substr($data,0,$skip);
```

Finds all Set-Cookie and all the cookies:

```
    $e = 0;
    while(true){
      $s = stripos($head,'Set-Cookie: ',$e);
      if (!$s){break;}
      $s += 12;
      $e = strpos($head,';',$s);
      $cookie = substr($head,$s,$e-$s) ;
      $s = strpos($cookie,'=');
      $key = substr($cookie,0,$s);
      $value = substr($cookie,$s);
      $cookies[$key] = $value;
    }
```

Then convert $cookies array back to a string:

```
    $cookie = '';
    $delim = '';
    foreach ($cookies as $k => $v){
      $cookie .= "$delim$k$v";
      $delim = '; ';
    }
  }
```

Do Login:

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.secure.pixiv.net";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
```

With cookie from first request:

```
$request[] = "Cookie: $cookie";
$postData = 'mode=login&return_to=%2F&pixiv_id=username&pass=password';
$url = 'https://www.secure.pixiv.net/login.php';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
$head = substr($data,0,$skip);
$data = substr($data,$skip);
echo $data;
```

**end of update**

---

I went directly to:

```
https://www.secure.pixiv.net/login.php
```

Using the cookie from `http://www.pixiv.net/`

For sure  postData was wrong:

```
   $postData='
        mode=login
        &return_to=%2F
        &pixiv_id=#####
        &pass=#####
        &skip=1
    ';
```

It add all the spaces and newline characters:

```
        mode=login
        &return_to=%2F
        &pixiv_id=#####
        &pass=#####
```

do it like this:

```
$postData = 'mode=login&return_to=%2F&pixiv_id=username&pass=password';
```

I did not use these:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.pixiv.net');
```

I added the cookie to the HTTP Header:

```
$request[] = "Cookie:PHPSESSID=b2e3185bd045475a2174fb28fb642569;
```

These I use just in case there is trouble and are not needed.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

### This Worked

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.secure.pixiv.net";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
$request[] = "Cookie:PHPSESSID=b2e3185bd045475a2174fb28fb642569; p_ab_id=3";
$post = 'mode=login&return_to=%2F&pixiv_id=username&pass=password';
$url = 'https://www.secure.pixiv.net/login.php';
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);


$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)){
    $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $info = rawurldecode(var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true));
 // Get the cookies:

  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $requestHeader= substr($data,0,$skip);
  $data = substr($data,$skip);
  echo $data;
```

}

Comment: This is weird; I tried to copy your code exactly as you wrote it (while changing the Cookie's PHPSESSID and p_ab_id by visiting the login page directly and copying it), but nothing shows. I get a blank page. How do I know whether it worked?

Comment: any non-alpha and numeric characters in your username or password? If so you need to urlencode the $postData  $postData = `urlencode('mode=login&return_to=%2F&pixiv_id=username&pass=password');`

Comment: The username and password I created are all in pure letters, no symbols or even numbers. Does it have something to do with the Cookie needing to accompany the same unique HTTP header?

Comment: Working Again, very solid.

Comment: I ran your code exactly, with the credentials changed. The resulting pixiv2.html states a 301 moved message and some header details. Is there some way to view "mypage" in the browser itself? I can't tell whether the 301 means its working or not. Oh, and pixivLogin.html doesn't exist. I think you forgot to save it.

Comment: The code was broken in to 3 blocks, `pixivLogin.html ` is the middle block, I closed the blocks to make one block of the final code.  301 is not good. That is a permanent redirect.

Comment: Update: Using your script, I added some alerts in to pinpoint what could be the issue. In the second block with the actual POST, "if (curl_errno($ch))" succeeds and the error is "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate". I added the SSL lines that you told me to remove before, and pixiv2.html now returns 302 Found Server, but I don't see anything visual. How should I proceed from here to see if it worked?

Comment: Okay, it's working now. Thank you very much! I managed to get to mypage.php. Sorry for all of the trouble caused.

Answer (score 1):

To post make sure you have a proper header set. your variable $httpHeader is defined with all the attributes having the same key '0' and therefore are overwritten each other.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending in a custom Host: header which doesn't match the host name of the URL you're using, which is suspicious and most likely wrong.

I'd advice you to not set a custom Host: header but let curl do its own magic for that, which probably is what you want.